# Pygame scrolling background glitch

Tags: python, pygame

```
bgx = 0
bgx2 = bgx + width
def move():
    bgx -= 40
    bgx2 -= 40
While True:
    if bgx <= width *-1:
        bgx = width
    if bgx2 <= width*-1:
        bgx2 = width

    display.blit(bg,[bgx,bgy])
    display.blit(bc,[bgx2,bgy2])
```

I am trying to create a scrolling bg , whenever I click a key move function is called

When it's time for the second image with bgx2 to show up on screen ,a glitch like something happens like in the attached image

[Glitch that happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHaPP.jpg)

What is the reason for that
Is the code drawing a new "second" image every loop instead of scrolling?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hudSa.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the modulo (%) operator to calculate the coordinates:

```py
bgx = 0
bgx2 = bgx + height

def move():
    global bgx, bgx2 
    bgx = (bgx - 40) % height
    bgx2 = bgx - height
```